# how to create an overlaying frame with qt4 in python

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt, frame

I would like to know if it is possible and how to create an overlaying frame (or any other widget) at a fixed position that would overlaying the content of the MainWindow with PyQt4.

The idea is to get a html-like render we can get with `position: fixed` or `position: absoute`. From what i know, all widgets have to inherit from the MainWindow's widget but is there a way to change this behavior or any way to simulate a widget with such level ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is to insert an object inside a frame that uses a layout, and avoid respecting that layout.
I am afraid the only thing i can come up with in your situation is either to avoid using layouts altogether (but that's very uncomfortable) or to extend a layout class and place the frame outside of the layout.

To make your frame stay on top, look for z-order.
http://qt-project.org/search/tag/z-order

Comment: Do you mean i have to add a specific rule for my frame in the inherited class to avoid it to fit the layouts ? After that do you know if all the layout in my window should use this class or only the "main" layout have to ?

Comment: Yes, have a layout that does an exception for that frame, and only the main layout should be this, for the other layouts you should use the normal layouts.